# How to prove a field with characteristic zero has a subfield isomorphic to the rationals

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

Here's a ring theory question in Hungerford algebra book:
**$R$ is an integral domain with $\operatorname{Char}(R)=0$ prove the following.**

A) $R$ has a subring isomorphic to the integers.

> I proved this one easily.

B) every field $F$ of the characteristic zero has a subfield isomorphic to the rationals.

> I took $\phi: \Bbb Z \to F$ such that $\phi(n)=n.1_F$ and proved it was a injective homomorphism function since the Char is zero. Now I said that $F$ contains $\Bbb Z)$ (right?)
> How do I now say that $\Bbb Z$ is in $F$ too?

Now I know that the set of  rationals is the fraction field of $\Bbb Z$ and that if $f$ contained a integral domain $R$ and $K$ was a field that contained $R$ too then there is a subfield $E$ that is isomorphic to $F$. I want to use this theorem. Is my approach correct so far?

Comment: You can just directly map $m/n$ to $m\cdot 1\cdot (n\cdot 1)^{-1}$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @StinkingBishop well, that's better and straightforward. Thank you. But I have 2 questions. If I go with your hint then I won't need part A right? That's kinda weird. And how did you come up with this? Is it a well known trick?

Comment: Part $A$ is valid in any integral domain of characteristic zero; part $B$ is only valid in *fields* of characteristic zero. You assume more - you can prove more. As for how I came up with that - what else could it be? You want to make injection $i:\mathbb Q\to F$, $i(1)=1$, then obviously $m\mapsto m\cdot 1, n\mapsto n\cdot 1$ and then $m/n=mn^{-1}$ must map to $(m\cdot 1)(n\cdot 1)^{-1}$.